# sscanf reads string but %n returns 0

Tags: c, gcc, scanf

I'm looking at a piece of code who's intention is to read one line at a time from a multi line string, and do stuff with the first 30 characters of each line. We hit a case where sscanf copies the content of "buff" into "list", but "count" is set to 0.

// Here is the code in question:

```
void foo(char * buff)
{   
   char line[31] = {0};
   int count = 0;
   int result = sscanf(buff, "%30[^\n]%*c%n", line, &count);
   printf("result = %d line = %s count = %d\n", result, line, count);
}

foo("test\n");
foo("test");
```

output:

```
result = 1 line = test count = 5
result = 1 line = test count = 0
```

The return from sscanf in the second case indicates one field read and "line" contains "test", so clearly, four characters were read from the input.  By definition, %n should report 4.

Comment: Note that end is of type char, not of type char* !  To make end a char *: "char *cur = buff, *end = buff + strlen(buff);"  Conclusions: a) Better put each variable declaration on a separate line.  b) put the asterisk at the variable name.

Comment: Your code is incomplete - the declaration / initialization of count is not shown.

Comment: The code will lead to buffer overflows: You are reading up to 1024 characters into a character array of length 31.

Comment: That was a copy past bug.  Also, the expected value for "count" is 5.

Comment: It really helps if you actually check the return of the `Xscanf` family of functions. Think about what is happening with the format string `"%1024[^\n]%*c%n"` for the string `"test"`? Where does the read stop? Where is the `'\n'` that will trigger the end of read? Then what is the next character that will be read and discarded with `%*c`. At that point is `%n` still valid? (`gcc` bug? -- no...)

Comment: Apologies for the sloppy code example.  I've cleaned it up.  sscanf always stops at the first null.  The only thing the [^\n] does is stop the read early if their does happen to be a '\n' in the string.  So for "test", the read stops after 4 characters, which means %n should set "count" to 4.

Comment: @GreggH: no; there must be a character for the `%*c` to process — and when there isn't a newline, or when the input string is not so long that the `%30[^\n]` is satisfied before it runs out of string, then `%*c` fails so the `%n` is not processed either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my understanding, the format specifier "%1024[^\n]%*c%n" will not match your string "test":  First (part "%1024[^\n]"), you read up to 1024 characters (excluding '\n') - that would be "test".  Then (part "%*c"), you attempt to read one further character but don't store it.  Since your string "test" is already eaten up at that point, parsing stops unsuccessfully.  Most likely, sscanf nevertheless has already modified all out arguments that have been processed so far, that's why "line" still already contains the string "test".

Here's the code that I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(const char *buff)
{
   char line[32] = {0};
   int count = 255;
   int fields = 0;

   fields = sscanf(buff, "%31[^\n]%n%*c", line, &count);
   printf("line = \"%s\"  count = %d  fields = %d\n", line, count, fields);
}


int main() {
   foo("test\n");
   foo("test");
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
line = "test"  count = 4  fields = 1
line = "test"  count = 4  fields = 1
```

With the format string `"%31[^\n]%*c%n"` I get (and, yes, also for 1024):

```
line = "test"  count = 5  fields = 1
line = "test"  count = 255  fields = 1
```

which is with gcc 4.6.3.

Comment: Last comment in full: In definitions I've seen, %n in the format string gives you, "the number of characters read from the input SO FAR by this scanf call."  I tried changing the format string to "%1024[^\n]%n%*c" and still count was 0. sscanf's return code gives you the number of fields successfully read and in this case it returns 1.  So if the count values were set to 0 because the entire format string wasn't matched, is this the correct behavior or a gcc bug? It seems to me that since 4 bytes were read from the input before the %*c failed to match, "count" should be 4 in this case.

Comment: After you updated your example above, the format string is still "%30[^\n]%*c%n", such that the output that you show seems perfectly plausible: For "test", scanning _stops_ at %*c and thus does not reach %n, and thus does not write to count.  This is in accordance with what the standard says, as others have also confirmed.  It _would_ be a bug if, as you say, also for "%1024[^\n]%n%*c" and an input string "test" count was not written.

Answer (score 2):

Neither suppressed assignments nor `%n` conversion specifications are counted in the return value from the `scanf()` family of functions.  That means you cannot tell if a suppressed assignment was matched, nor can you tell whether the `%n` was processed unless there was an assignment after it — or you initialize the variable that will be assigned by the `%n` conversion specification with, for example, a negative value and look to see whether it has changed afterwards.

Looking at your test code, both input strings are converted so that `test` is read; this is expected and what you see.

With the format string `"%31[^\n]%*c%n"`, after the conversion of `test` is complete, with the input `"test\n"`, the suppressed assignment conversion succeeds (reading the newline) so the `%n` is processed.  With the input `"test"`, though, the suppressed assignment fails (there's no character left to process after `test` is read), so the `%n` is not processed either.  Processing stops when there's a problem — a mismatched literal character in the format string, or a failed conversion (whether an assignment is suppressed or not).

So, the behaviour you see is what the standards require (see the POSIX specification of [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html), for example).

Remember that white space in a format string is equivalent to optional white space in the data.